# Compareble Comparator java?

Tags: java, сортировка

Можно ли в методе `compareTo` сравнивать два поля? Попыталась сравнить то сортирует. Для чего тогда интерфейс `comparator`???

```
 @Override
        public int compareTo(A o) {
            if (this.getAge()>o.getAge())
            return 1;
            else if (this.getAge()<o.getAge())
                return -1;
            else return this.getName().compareTo(o.getName());
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Реализация интерфейса `Сomparator` существует отдельно от объекта, который вы сравниваете. Таким образом вы можете создать несколько разных компараторов, которые будут сравнивать объекты по-разному. Например один компаратор по полю `name`, другой по полю `age`, а третий сразу по обоим этим полям. Реализация же интерфейса `Сomparable` находится в самих объектах, которые вы сравниваете и выбрать какую-то другую его реализацию вы не можете. С другой стороны, если вашы объекты реализуют `Сomparable`, вы не обязаны использовать какие-то дополнительные компараторы для такого же сравнения.

Answer (score 1):

1. Да, можно сравнивать сколько угодно полей.
2. Интерфейс Comparator используется если вам надо просто сравнить 2 одинаковых объекта, но отсортировать эти объекты надо не в стандартной последовательности. Например, по умолчанию письма могут сортировать по дате получения - для этого используется compareto. Но все остальные кастомные сортировки - лучше делать через интерфейс Comparator. Тогда их можно будет расширять бесконечно и кастомизировать.